# Explain what good/bad tags are when asking whether users want to create one

Tags: feature-request, tags

> [image]

This nice message appears when users create new tags. It's a good way to remind them of the fact that they should be spelled properly and that there might be existing tags.

But: The dialog says nothing about what a good or bad tag is. We have so many useless, ambiguous and meta-tags that I'd prefer if at least some of the people who create new tags are reminded of our rules.

So, why not add a paragraph like:

> Please don't create a tag that does not have any meaning, especially if it was the only tag in your question. Also, tags that do not describe the *content* are considered [meta tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and should not be added to questions too.

Proposals for another wording are welcome.

In fact, the [privileges page](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/create-tags) does not say anything about what good or bad tags are either. Given that we care so much about question and answer quality, we should definitely raise the bar for our tags as well.

Comment: I like the idea of giving users more guidance, but I would be concerned that adding a "paragraph" to the tag warning will make people not bother to read what's already there. Maybe a link to a wiki post about tagging would be more useful than adding a long run-on paragaph.

Comment: I usually argue similarly, but in this case, we are addressing users with a minimum reputation level of 300 or 1500, depending on the site. So you don't run into the same issues as with new users. Also, the information I'd like to add is not secondary—it's important if you are creating a tag. And it's only relevant there.